# I can't play youtube 1080 videos?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, desktop-environments, cpu, gpu

ubuntu is really slow vlc is consuming 50% of cpu on average 
it spikes to more than 100% here and there , and when I play 1080 youtube videos laptop goes (partially) unresponsive.

```
➜  ~ sudo lshw
linuxbox                  
    description: Notebook
    product: 20157 (System SKUNumber)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo G580
    serial: WB06808388WB0206130J
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=unknown boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ChiefRiver System frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=unknown sku=System SKUNumber uuid=077173A0-B66B-11E1-924E-8C060B8953EF
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Emerald Lake 2
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: FAB1
       serial: WB06808388
       slot: Part Component
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: 62CN40WW
          date: 07/27/2012
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 4032KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video pc98 acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPU Socket - U3E1
          size: 2652MHz
          capacity: 3100MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1-Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 6
          slot: L1-Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 7
          slot: L2-Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 8
          slot: L3-Cache
          size: 3MiB
          capacity: 3MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 34
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M471B5273DH0-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 66649E75
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: EBJ41UF8BCS0-DJ-F
             vendor: Elpida
             physical id: 2
             serial: 519B0EF3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             physical id: 3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=ivb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f2000000-f2ffffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:31 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:27 memory:f3000000-f33fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:25 memory:f3600000-f360ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-79-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-79-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:f3615000-f361500f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f3619000-f36193ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-79-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: BCM20702A0
                      vendor: Broadcom Corp
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:1.4
                      version: 1.12
                      serial: 08EDB99AD0FE
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f3610000-f3613fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 memory:f3500000-f35fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 01
                serial: 08:ed:b9:9a:d0:fd
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                resources: irq:17 memory:f3500000-f3503fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f3400000-f34fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: enp4s0
                version: 10
                serial: f0:de:f1:ff:11:be
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:30 memory:f3400000-f343ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f3618000-f36183ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-79-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Mass storage device
                      product: Flash Card Reader/Writer
                      vendor: Generic
                      physical id: 6
                      bus info: usb@2:1.6
                      logical name: scsi6
                      version: 1.00
                      serial: 058F63666435
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                      configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=250mA speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-disk
                         description: SCSI Disk
                         product: Card  Reader
                         vendor: Multiple
                         physical id: 0.0.0
                         bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
                         logical name: /dev/sdc
                         version: 1.00
                         capabilities: removable
                         configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                       *-medium
                            physical id: 0
                            logical name: /dev/sdc
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:26 ioport:4088(size=8) ioport:4094(size=4) ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4090(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:f3617000-f36177ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f3614000-f36140ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST9500325AS
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: LVM1
             serial: 5VEV3MZY
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=179afccb
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                logical name: /var/lib/docker/aufs
                version: 1.0
                serial: 3b7dbebd-e767-4086-96ab-c17d3dbe5f75
                size: 46GiB
                capacity: 46GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-03-19 15:00:53 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2017-06-19 02:19:35 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2017-06-19 02:19:42 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 4870MiB
                capacity: 4870MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 4870MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:2
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                logical name: /home
                version: 1.0
                serial: 40644ca7-3549-4753-9b09-a77a69123449
                size: 414GiB
                capacity: 414GiB
                capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-03-19 15:00:55 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/home modified=2017-06-19 02:19:50 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2017-06-19 02:19:50 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: EXT4 volume
             product: ST1000LM048-2E71
             vendor: Linux
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             logical name: /media/aeid/secondary
             version: 1.0
             serial: 8aecbfda-c4d7-42be-9147-27360168b4a2
             size: 931GiB
             capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
             configuration: ansiversion=5 created=2017-06-15 20:15:02 filesystem=ext4 label=secondary lastmountpoint=/media/aeid/secondary logicalsectorsize=512 modified=2017-06-19 02:25:38 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2017-06-19 02:25:38 sectorsize=4096 state=mounted
  *-battery
       product: Smart Battery
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 1
       version: 2008
       serial: 1.0
       slot: Rear
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: TBD by ODM
       product: TBD by ODM
       vendor: TBD by ODM
       physical id: 2
       version: 1.0
       serial: TBD by ODM
       capacity: 32768mWh
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:ff:45:30
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

in a nutshell I have an `i5 3210M cpu` , `GeForce 610M/PCIe/SSE2` `8G ram`

What could be the problem.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1rcgkP0.png